# How can I make MSAL4J and azure-security-keyvault-* work together?

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal, azure-security

I would like to authenticate with MSAL4J and the certificate stored in Azure Key Vault (AKV). The certificate is a self-signed Azure Key Vault certificate.

I could find an example based on a certificate and key stored locally (file system) but not a certificate created and stored in AKV. How to use the certificate, key, and secret objects obtained from `azure-security-keyvault-*` with MSAL4J?

1. The key from `azure-security-keyvault-keys` is `com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.models.KeyVaultKey`, but MSAL4J expects `java.security.PrivateKey`.
2. How to apply the secret obtained from `azure-security-keyvault-secrets` to decrypt the private key?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is supported? As far as I know certificated-based authentication is not supported.
MSAL uses either public clients or confidential clients.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#daemon-app-that-calls-a-web-api-in-the-daemons-name
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications

However, I did find this on their wiki:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Client-Credentials

There are two types of client secrets in MSAL4J:

- Application Secrets
- Certificates

You need to instantiate a confidential client application; if you have a certificate:

```
String PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID;
String AUTHORITY;
PrivateKey PRIVATE_KEY;  
X509Certificate PUBLIC_KEY;

IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY);
ConfidentialClientApplication app = 
    ConfidentialClientApplication
        .builder(PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID, credential)
        .authority(AUTHORITY)
        .build();
```

Then acquire a token:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens#confidential-client-applications

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/src/client/ConfidentialClientApplication.ts
You would need to use: `acquireTokenByClientCredential`
https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_node.confidentialclientapplication.html#acquiretokenbyclientcredential

Also see:

- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/msal4j-sdk/src/integrationtest/java/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j/CertificateHelper.java
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: I have the certificate, but it was stored in Key Vault. My problem is how could I turn the certificate (and key) from Azure Key Vault into the type which confidential client application is expected?

The tricky part is the private key. It is stored as a secret (not key) in key vault. It is in x-application/pkcs12 format. How can I turn it into java.security.PrivateKey?